# Architecture design for an MVC 5 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

We are building an MVC 5 application, a consultant has come up with a high level architecture, not sure that it is the best as it uses SOAP, I thought the current standard was REST.  Does anyone have any recommendations?  Guidance?  Best practices??

The application basically is to be used by authenticated users, who can perform certain functions like update details.  Buy things using a merchant gateway etc.  Also logging and testing is important as well.  I know this might seem like a general query, wasn't sure where to ask

[image]

Comment: SOAP or REST serialization is mostly based on what your interoperability targets are. Everyone can read/write SOAP but noone LIKES reading/writing XML. SOAP is still a very valid standard, it's just not that easy-to-use when the target is something that prefers JSON or POX. Sincew i see AJAX & JQuery, i'm assuming a JavaScript runtime and JSON is defenitly prefered. I'd also like to advise using the WebAPI AspNetWebStack for the front end SI.

Comment: The other issue I was having was if entity framework is used then why is the service implementation talking to entity framework? shouldn't the POCO classes be doing that?

Comment: The thing i'm confused about is why would you use a ORM and a custom DAL? wouldn't 1 of the two suffice?

Comment: good point.. if entity framework is used we don't need a DAL yeah?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's all depends on the application you are developing.

WCF is needed for advanced authentication, transactions, binding scenarios. If you don't need it, you can go with MVC Web API for `Customer Portal WebServices`. Web API is very easy to use, it is flexible and fast. Of cource REST is better. Don't use SOAP if it is possible. REST is MUCH easier to integrate with. Not only for C# client but also for ANY client you need - HTML, Mobile etc.

Regarding DAL: I see recommendation to use Stored Procedures. I am not a fan of stored procs, but sometimes it is the best solution. So I would recommend to use Entity Framework if it possible and stored procs with Entity Framework if you cannot avoid using stored procs.

Looks like the application is going to be pretty large. `Business Entities` is a notion that architecture will be domain driven(DDD). Take a look at CQRS pattern. It is a very good alternative. With help of CQRS you can avoid typical issues of DDD. When you need a little different models for querying and for commands like Create or Edit.

Comment: Web API supports authentication as well yeah?  I agree about the stored procs, but unfortunately its an existing database and we are not allowed to change it, and it contains stored procs.  In regards to business entities, I assumed these were just the POCO objects from EF 6

Comment: @user2206329 Web API does supports Authentication. WCF has more extensibility and features to do so. But I think Web API authentication is enough in 99% scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Soap would be the format used to transmit the data ( XML formatted data transmitted to or received from a client or service. Rest has more to do with how data is passed to the service as a parameter of a url eg. `http://sample service/method/data`

Perhaps there is a requirement that the service shown in the diagram is owned by a third party ( like the payment gateway ) and they have chosen soap as the transmission protocol.

If the service is yours, I would ask the consultant why soap and WCF vs webAPI and JSON.
Not enough information presented to understand what the constraints on the design are.

Comment: The payment gateway is definitely a 3rd party (and might only accept SOAP), but the rest of it is a green field project and we can dictate how to build it...